# Send Message to specific user SignalR

Tags: signalr

Creating a chat application and want send message to a specific user.
I can send messages to a specific user but the message is appearing for others contact also.
Example: Dev is sending message to Josh

Dev Send "Hello" to Josh

Josh is having contacts as

- Amit
- Rita
- Dev

and josh right now talking Amit at that time Dev message appear is Amit chat Screen

```
This is my ChatHub.cs---------
    public void Send(string receiver, string message)
    {
       
            if (receiver != string.Empty && message != string.Empty)
            {
                string Sender = Context.User.Identity.Name;

                Clients.Group(receiver).broadcastMessage(Sender, message);
                Clients.Group(Sender).broadcastMessage(Sender, message);

                ChatRepository CR = new ChatRepository();
                CR.SaveConversation(Sender, receiver, message);
            }
    }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, name);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

please help I can't find the solution
Thank you

Edit: my approach to send message to specific user please check as discussed in Comments

```
 public void Send(string receiver, string message)
    {

        if (receiver != string.Empty && message != string.Empty)
        {
            string Sender = Context.User.Identity.Name;

            if ("Success" == CR.CheckingForConnetionBetweenUser(receiver, Sender))  //Checking connectivity from a XYZTable 
            {                                                                //"Success" value from DB shows users are connected to each other 
                Clients.Group(receiver).broadcastMessage(Sender, message);
            }
            Clients.Group(Sender).broadcastMessage(Sender, message);


            CR.SaveConversation(Sender, receiver, message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to debug OnConnected first, check if Name has correct value. Is it possible that your clients establish connection before they get some claims?

Also, please, take a look into this article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-claims-to-customize-identity-handling

If you will provide IUserIdProvider service to return Name claim or if you will map userId to ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier claim in your login code, you will be able to filter your SignalR clients using this method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubclients-1.user?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_SignalR_IHubClients_1_User_System_String_

Default implementation for reference: https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core/DefaultUserIdProvider.cs

And you will be able to call client like this:

```
await Clients.User(receiver).broadcastMessage(Sender, message);
```

SignalR already know which principal is attached to which connection, so probably no need to create group for each user.

Comment: can please explain the group and user difference ?

Comment: @AnilMohanKukarati you can imagine groups like named collections of connections. And when  you write Groups.Add(..., groupName) you add connection to collection named groupName. So there you can have connections of several different users. But when you use User, SignalR filters established connections to find one, that have specified userId. So it will iterate through all connections, on each iteration it will call GetUserId method of available IUserIdProvider (default or one that you provided) and will send mssage if id is equal to param you provided.

Comment: @AnilMohanKukarati so, in a word, to send something to group, connections should be added there first. If user have several connections, it doesn't mean all of them will be added to group if you add one of his connections. You will need to add code to add all new connections like you did. But when you want to send by User method, all connections of specified user will receive message. You only need to assign correct claims or implement and register IUserIdProvider

Comment: @AnilMohanKukarati you are using asp.net core, right?

Comment: I  am using Asp.net MVC 5

Comment: I  am getting confuse

Comment: right now I am handling this from Backend by saving connection between two users

Comment: "Harry" is having contacts of other users on the list. So when Rita sends a message to Harry (let say Hello!)  at that time Harry to talking to "Josh". "Rita" message appears in the conversation between "Harry" and "josh" on the josh chat screen.

Comment: @AnilMohanKukarati sounds interesting.
Sorry, i was sending links about ASP.NET Core  SignalR.
So, Josh see this message and Harry doesn't or vice versa?
Oh, so, you can have private chat conversations between different users, not just one common chat screen? If so, is it possible that you are missing condition on front end to check if current dialog contains message sender?

Comment: yes, not one common chat screen? and right  I am handling it from the backend by making the connection between them if receiver has also opened the same chat screen of the sender.

Comment: @AnilMohanKukarati sorry, what do you mean by connection between clients?
In that part of code you sent it currently looks like you are sending message to user if he is receiver.
Also, is it happening after relogins or just from the start?

Comment: @AnilMohanKukarati sorry, do you mean you add them to separate group when they open the same chat? maybe you can send a bit more code for this moment if possible

Comment: lets in the database XYZtable Rita opened the Harry Chat screen, Harry Opened Josh's chat screen and josh opened the harry chat screen. So here josh and harry are talking to each other. This info is stored in an XYZtable. So when Rita sends a message to harry I go to my XYZtable and check whether harry is opened Rita's chat screen or not and return the string as success and unsuccess. According to the table, it's not because harry is right now opened Josh's chat screen. So it returns "Unsuccess" but if harry opened Rita's chat screen it a success and harry can see the message.

Comment: saving this info in XYZtable when the user clicks on one of the contacts to chat. When users click they make a connection.

Comment: I have edited my question above with the solution I am using to send messages to specific user please check and let me know if it is the correct to do way or not. Thanks

Comment: @AnilMohanKukarati yeah, looks like it should work, will think what can go wrong and let you know

Comment: ok, Thank you so much @Anton :) :). For now, it is working.